# Display: inline with scroll overflow-y

Tags: html, css

I can not set the scroll to this item that has the property `display: inline`
I tried it with `white-space: nowrap` but does not work
while repositioning `overflow`  under a `height`

I did not have any changeis the second question I ask above getilmente give me a hand

> **Solution:**
>
> Used `inline-block`

```css
#Contenitore_Titoli
{
width: 1535px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 35px;
text-align: center;
}

.Elenco_Utenti
{
width: 360px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}

.Elenco_Contatti_Whatsapp
{
width: 371px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}

.Elenco_Contatti_Skype
{

width: 371px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
float: left;
text-align: center;


}

.Elenco_Contatti_Facebook
{

width: 371px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
float: left;
text-align: center;


}

.Contenitore_Lista_Contatti
{
border-top: 1px solid gray;
width: 1480;
height: 25px;
}

#Contatti
{
width: 360px;
height: 31px;
float: left;
color: red;
display: inline;
text-align: center;
}

#Contatti_Whatsapp_Titolo
{
width: 371px;
height: 31px;
color: red;
display: inline;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}

#Contatti_Skype_Titolo
{
width: 371px;
height: 31px;
color: red;
display: inline;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}

#Contatti_Facebook_Titolo
{
width: 371px;
height: 31px;
color: red;
display: inline;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}

#Contenuto_Lista_Guide_Div
{
display: inline;
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 637px
}
```

```html
<div id="Contenitore_Titoli">
 <div id="Contatti">Nome Utente</div>
 <div id="Contatti_Whatsapp_Titolo">Whatsapp</div>
 <div id="Contatti_Skype_Titolo">Skype</div>
 <div id="Contatti_Facebook_Titolo">Facebook</div>
</div>
<div id="Contenuto_Lista_Guide_Div">
<div class="Contenitore_Lista_Contatti">
  <div class="Elenco_Utenti"> darkbit </div>
  <div class="Elenco_Contatti_Whatsapp"> 345956254</div>
  <div class="Elenco_Contatti_Skype"> pipposkype </div>
  <div class="Elenco_Contatti_Facebook">facebook</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try inline-block instead of inline.

Comment: Thanks solved :) with width too...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS property ***overflow*** to scroll after setting a ***height***.

For example, write a class like following:

```
.aClass{
  height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;    
}
```

You can see the overflow ***property*** here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp